# How can i create a new tab in myaccount page using custom module in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

How can i create a new tab in myaccount page using custom module in drupal.Is there any hooks for that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are handled using the menu item types [`MENU_LOCAL_TASK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/6) and [`MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/6). To add a tab for the user account page you need to use one of these as your menu item type, and also make sure the path is a child of the standard user path (`user/%user`).

Something like this:

```
$items['user/%user/mytab'] = array(
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'title' => 'My Tab',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_mytab_page',
  'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  'weight' => 10 // You can control the position of the tab with this property
);
```